# Can't loop through bs4.element.ResultSet type in python using Beautiful Soup

Tags: for-loop, beautifulsoup, google-chrome-devtools, python-3.6, resultset

Please refer the code :

````
```soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
rlist=soup.find_all('div',{"class": "WMbnJf gws-localreviews__google-review"})# whole orange box class="WMbnJf gws-localreviews__google-review <REVIEW ID GOES HERE>

print('I REACHED HERE')
try:
    print('rlist type: ',type(rlist))
except:
    print('rlist:\n',rlist)
    #result=[]

for r in rlist:
    r1=r.find('div',{"class": "jxjCjc"})
    print('\n','r1 type: ',type(r1),'\n\n') ##

    r2=r1.find('div',{"class": 'TSUbDb'})
    personname=r2.text
    print(personname) ##
    try:
        r3=r1.find('div',{"class": 'Jtu6Td'})
        personreview=r3.text
    except:
        personreview='-' #Blank Review

    print(personreview)

    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Reviews (placeid, name, review)
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )''', (pid, personname, personreview) )
    conn.commit()```
````

I ran the code several times to find that the whole for-loop isn't working. Can't figure this out on my own, please help!!

Here's the code before the beautiful soup parser:

````
browser.get(placeidurl)                        

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
menu_bt = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                       (By.XPATH, '//g-dropdown-button[@class=\'dkSGpd NkCsjc\']'))
                   )
menu_bt.click()

recent_rating_bt=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//g-menu[@role='menu']//div[@class='znKVS'][text()='Newest']")

recent_rating_bt.click()
time.sleep(5)```
````

Comment: you'll have to supply more code than that, can't do much with what you provided other than what I'm seeing is that the page is likely dynamic. The classes you are looking for probably are rendered/change each time, thus when you use bs4 to find it, it's not there

Comment: @chitown88 Here i have used Selenium and beautiful soup. Correct me if I'm wrong but as far as i know, both work fine with dynamic sites as well, don't they? Otherwise could you suggest me something else? Thankyou in advance

Comment: They are 2 different things. Selenium is a browser simulator. It’ll create a process that simulates the actions of opening a browser and “clicking” around. You CAN also parse the html with selenium. Beautifulsoup is solely to parse the html. You’ll need to get the html response first.

Comment: So beautifulsoup doesn’t work with dynamic sites in the sense that it doesn’t know the difference. It just understands html, and you need something else (like selenium or requests) to fetch the html source code for a site.

Comment: So what I mean by saying you need to give more info, is I need to see how your getting the html. So the part of the code before you create the beautifulsoup object.

Comment: @chitown88 I've added the code, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: No inconvenience, there’s just not much more one can do if can’t see the whole process. I’ll take a look as soon as I can.

Comment: And now looking, you still haven’t provided it all. I can’t run the code without placeidurl defined. I can’t run cur.execute, etc. please provide enough code to run on our ends so that we can give a working solution.

Comment: I know you’re new, but conventional practice on SO is: describe the problem (IE. tells us what you are trying to do, what isn’t working, and what the output should look like). Then give enough of the code so that we can reproduce that on our end. It’s like taking your car in to get checked, telling the mechanic it’s not running correctly, but then not giving them the keys to start the engine or even letting the mechanic look under the hood. There’s only so much the mechanic can determine if they can’t debug/troubleshoot.